# Creating one instance of an object and using the same instance in different class files

Tags: java, class, object, instance

I have been searching around the internet about Creating an instance of a object in one class and using that same instance in a different class. I have not found any posts though that apply to what I want to do. Here is an example of what I want to do.

---

```
public class ThisClass{
  public ThisClass{
    //This is the object I want to create
  }
}
```

---

```
public class FirstClass{
  public ThisClass thisclass = new ThisClass();
}
```

---

```
public class SecondClass{
  //Now in SecondClass I want to be able to access the instance of ThisClass
  //I created in FirstClass
}
```

---

Any ideas on what to do here that wont be too complex and make the code a nightmare to look at?

Comment: Why not create an instance ThisClass and pass it to FirstClass and SecondClass as part of their constructors, or have a method on ThisClass that can return a specified instance? This is all assuming you don't actually want a singleton

Comment: Do you ever want there to be more than one instance of `ThisClass` in your application?

Comment: `SecondClass fred = new SecondClass(); fred.setFirstInstance(thisclass)`

Comment: @francis Why not `new SecondClass(thisInstance);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three solutions came into my mind :

1. Make `ThisClass` *singleton* - in this way you will never be able to instantiate more than one class of `ThisClass` type.
2. Create an *instance* of `ThisClass` type and pass it through constructor to all other classes.
3. Create an *abstract class / interface* which holds a static instance variable of type `ThisClass`, and then extend/implement this abstract class / interface in classes you want to have the same `ThisClass` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
public class ThisClass {
    public ThisClass() {
        // This is the object I want to create
    }
}

public class FirstClass {
    private ThisClass thisClass = new ThisClass();

    public ThisClass getThisClass() {
        return thisClass;
    }

}

public class SecondClass {
    //Now in SecondClass I want to be able to access the instance of ThisClass
    //I created in FirstClass
    private ThisClass thisClass;

    public SecondClass(ThisClass thisClass) {
        this.thisClass = thisClass;
    }
}

public class ThirdClass {
    public ThirdClass() {
        new SecondClass(new FirstClass().getThisClass());
    }
}
```